# Refinery CMS - Adding it to an existing site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refinerycms

So I have made a simple html + css + javascript website to test out my Refinery skills.

Embarrassingly, I've completely hit a brick wall! How can I add my own custom pages to Refinery CMS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you have to copy and paste your HTML through the actual system. Add css and javascript to the relevant asset directories of the actual gem.

Despite Refinery being the biggest open source CMS, Radiant CMS seems a lot better. More intuitive. Allows you to create templates in a more Wordpress-esque manner, creating editable regions: http://radiantcms.org